# Java Jung Graph clustering returns non-intuitive clusters

Tags: graph-theory, jung, jung2

I want to perform some graph clustering and since I am pretty much bound to Java, decided to give the java package Jung a try. As a simple graph I create two clusters of each 5vertices which are interconnected. I connect both clusters using one edge. I would expect after the graph clustering to retrieve 2 clusters of both size 5 but I get different results. This is the code:

```
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.cluster.VoltageClusterer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseGraph;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

public class CreateGraph {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Graph<V, E> where V is the type of the vertices
    // and E is the type of the edges
    Graph<Integer, String> g = new SparseGraph<Integer, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        g.addVertex((Integer) i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {
            if (i != ii) {
                g.addEdge("EdgeA-" + i + ii, i, ii);
            }
        }
    }
    // cluster 2
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
        g.addVertex((Integer) i);
    }

    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int ii = 5; ii < 10; ii++) {
            if (i != ii) {
                g.addEdge("EdgeB-" + i + ii, i, ii);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(g.toString());

    g.addEdge("Edge-connector", 1, 5);

    System.out.println("Creating voltageclusterer");

    VoltageClusterer<Integer, String> vc = new VoltageClusterer<Integer, String>(g, 2);

    Collection<Set<Integer>> clusters = vc.cluster(2);

    for (Set<Integer> s : clusters) {
        System.out.println("set is " + s.size());
        for (Integer ss : s) {
            System.out.println("Element " + ss);
        }
    }
}
 }
```

and the output:
+

1. set is 1

   - Element 8
2. set is 9

   - Element 0
   - Element 1
   - Element 2
   - Element 3
   - Element 4
   - Element 5
   - Element 6
   - Element 7
   - Element 9

Anyone any idea? (suggestions with regard to other approaches are also welcome, as long as they are in Java).

Answer (score 1):

VoltageClusterer has a random element: depending on how the dice roll (and how many times you roll them--see below), sometimes the answer that you get will be quite odd, as it was in this case.  You can specify the random seed using `setRandomSeed()`.

The reason you ran into this problem is that the Javadoc for the `VoltageClusterer` constructor is wrong: the numeric parameter that you're passing in is not the number of clusters; it's the number of *random samples* that are being generated.  Sorry about that; we'll fix it.

You almost certainly want to be using more random samples than 2.

The other clustering algorithms for which JUNG has implementations are deterministic.  `EdgeBetweennessClusterer` in particular will partition the graph as you expect if you tell it to remove one edge.